Yeshiva For Working Professional
I am single and currently work full time, but am looking for a Yeshiva Community to become part of during the evening/Shabbos (i.e. dorm there, night seder, etc).
Does something like this exist somewhere in the NY/NJ area (commutable to Manhattan)? For reference, I attended Modern-Orthdox Yeshivot K-12 but did not go to the year in Israel.

Would they give a valuable dorm spot to someone who wasn't full time? I also don't think it would be fair to assign you as chavruta to a full time boy who needs a chavruta to bond with over the morning seder and shiurim.
You can find a chavruta with this service
https://oraysa.org/chavrusa/search

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Like @ClintEastwood said hey probably wouldn't give you a dorm spot, but you might be able to find someone in the community who will rent you a room.

@ClintEastwood Gotcha, I hear what you're saying. I was more so looking for a program which specifically does part time learning in an organized fashion (so that I wouldn't leave a chavruta hanging during the morning seder/shidiurim).

Thanks @mbloch, and thanks for editing.

@AfronPie Did you speak to any of the yeshivos in NY/NJ area? Usually, you need to find a commited avrech and ask for possible compensation.

@AfronPie - do you specifically need your learning to revolve around an organized/regularly scheduled shiur or chabura or would it be enough to have a steady chavrusa or chavrusas within that yeshiva environment?

@EraserX I was thinking about what you mentioned, as Clint mentioned something similar. I was hoping to find an organized/regularly scheduled shiur/chabura, but if I can't find that then I will look into getting a few chavrusas.

you may want to check out landers college in queens

Welcome to MiYodea, which is best when used for more general "learn about Judaism" type questions (such as you might find in a book about Judaism or its Torah), instead of specific personal recommendations. I'd recommend reaching out to any Torah teachers you may have had in high school to help direct you to somewhere that might be a good fit

Please check out this yeshiva where I studied over a decade ago. They have night seders Sunday-Thursday and there is Davening there everyday
Yeshiva Ohr Yitzchok
1214 E 15TH ST
BROOKLYN, NY 11230-4807
yeshivaemail@gmail.com
(718) 258-7007
(917) 975-9606
Hatzlacha Rabbah!!

I am going to mark this as the answer. Though this isn't exactly what I am looking for (I think what I am looking for doesn't exist). I did reach out via the number listed and they said they typically serve men age 17-25 (at this time I fit into that age group) and that while the dorm may be possible it seems like it has limited space and would be more so for talmidim who are there full time (as @Clint Eastwood mentioned in the comments above would likely be the case).

Thank you for answering and thanks @mbloch and everyone else for your help.

My recommendation is to find an apartment to share or rent alone (depending on your finances) in one of the following locations and to pick a beis midrash as there are usually contacts who can set up chavrusos. Some of these might have options for shiurim you can attend.
Ordered by likely best fit I would suggest:

YU/RIETS in Washington Heights - for years they have catered to singles who are former students (and sometimes others) who are not officially studying there but want to live in proximity to a yeshiva environment.  You also have the option of local eateries and can possibly join their student Shabbos meals by paying as a guest (if someone knows that the current situation is different then please correct me).  They have Kollel Yom Rishon which is geared toward non-students.  It might not be the best option re: learning a consistent masechta, but if you contact someone there or at RIETS they might know of ideas for learning programs that would be a fit for you. It's still in Manhattan so you have the advantage of the subway if you work in the city. If you own a car, word to the wise to park it in a safe place (but I guess that goes for many places in NYC). Not the greatest neighborhood, but since you are coming from a Modern Orthodox background this might be the best cultural fit for you.
Kew Gardens Hills in Queens is commutable to Manhattan and there are a number of yeshiva options there where you might connect. Ohr Hachaim comes to mind and it's common to see outside neighborhood people learning there.  Beis Medrash L'Talmud (aka Landers) and Chofetz Chaim are also there and depending on where you find an apartment they might be more convenient (but I'm not aware on a first-hand basis how common it is for outsiders to learn there and whether they offer programs catering specifically to non-students).
There are other communities with working single professionals that are commutable to Manhattan which are a bit more yeshivish but you might still find your niche.  Passaic, NJ comes to mind and you can check out their Passaic Torah Institute and Passaic Clifton Community Kollel. Of course there is Brooklyn to but I'm not as familiar with the options that would cater to your situation.

If you have a decent personal network in any of these locations, it can affect the speed in which you set up your apartment and chavrusa. For some of these options, security has become a more serious issue over the years, so it would be advisable to inquire as to how visitors can gain building access for the beis midrash.
Much hatzlocha with your efforts!
- I have no official connection with any of these institutions.
- The above ideas are relevant to the present and might not be pertinent if someone views this question years from now.

Thank you for your comprehensive answer! I will definitely be looking into a few of these options.
